# javascript - moving for loop content into functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

I have a `for` loop to go through an array and display dates. I've written some code to convert the months from numbers to text. The code looks like this:

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //==== MONTH DATA
  var month = data[1];

  //==== DECLARE MONTH
  if (month == '01') { var month = "Jan" }
  if (month == '02') { var month = "Feb" }
  if (month == '03') { var month = "Mar" }
  if (month == '04') { var month = "Apr" }
  if (month == '05') { var month = "May" }
  if (month == '06') { var month = "June" }
  if (month == '07') { var month = "July" }
  if (month == '08') { var month = "Aug" }
  if (month == '09') { var month = "Sept" }
  if (month == '10') { var month = "Oct" }
  if (month == '11') { var month = "Nov" }
  if (month == '12') { var month = "Dec" }

  alert(month);
}
```

Now I want to use the month convertor in various for loops throughout my site. So I want to do something like put it in a function that I can fire everytime. For exmample:

```
function declareMonth(){
  //==== DECLARE MONTH
  if (month == '01') { var month = "Jan" }
  if (month == '02') { var month = "Feb" }
  if (month == '03') { var month = "Mar" }
  if (month == '04') { var month = "Apr" }
  if (month == '05') { var month = "May" }
  if (month == '06') { var month = "June" }
  if (month == '07') { var month = "July" }
  if (month == '08') { var month = "Aug" }
  if (month == '09') { var month = "Sept" }
  if (month == '10') { var month = "Oct" }
  if (month == '11') { var month = "Nov" }
  if (month == '12') { var month = "Dec" }
}

for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  //==== MONTH DATA
  var month = data[1];

  declareMonth();

  alert(month);
}
```

This doesn't work however. Could anyone explain how this can be done?

Comment: You've gotten a bit overenthusiastic about using `var`. No need to include `var` in all of your `if` statements where you do those assignments.

Comment: @nnnnnn not that he should be making 12 separate assignments anyway...

Comment: Well no, @Alnitak, obviously your answer is a much better way to go. Another point for the OP though, regarding your statement _"I have a jQuery for loop"_ - you are mistaken, because there is no jQuery anywhere in your question. What you have is a plain JavaScript for loop.

Comment: @coop This has nothing to do with jQuery. This is a plain javascript `for` loop.

Comment: Yes good points. Thanks for the advice, I'll try and cut it all down. And you're right about the javascript/jQuery!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *return* the month value.  You also need to write the function properly:

```
function getMonthName(n) {
    var months = ["Jan", "Feb", ... ];  // omitted for brevity
    return months[n - 1];
}
```

with usage:

```
for (var i=0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
  var month = data[1];
  var name = getMonthName(month);
  alert(name);
}
```

NB: the result will be `undefined` if the supplied month is out of range.

Comment: Genius! It solves my problem AND reduces the code a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're function is on the right track as an analogy, but javascript has some easier methods of doing what you did with less code.

### Use a hash

If we take your `if` example from above we can convert it to a hash and a simple function:

```
var monthName = function( num ){
  var months = {
    '01':'Jan', '02':'Feb',
    '03':'Mar', '04':'Apr',
    '05':'May', '06':'Jun',
    '07':'Jul', '08':'Aug',
    '09':'Sep', '10':'Oct',
    '11':'Nov', '12':'Dec'
  };

  return months[ num ];
};
```

This solution requires that the `num` parameter that the function accepts is a string.

<kbd>**[Heres a demo](http://jsbin.com/akedah/1/edit)**</kbd>

### Use an array

If you're calling your month using a number use an array:

```
var monthName = function( num ){
  var months = [
    'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',
    'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug',
    'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'
  ];

  return months[ num - 1 ];
};
```

<kbd>**[Heres a demo](http://jsbin.com/akedah/2/edit)**</kbd>